# Function SignInWithFacebook doesn't exist in Firebase Auth SDK for Flutter in macOS, but in Windows it exists

Tags: android, ios, facebook, firebase, flutter

I have started using Flutter this year, so I am not an expert.
I am trying to develop an app for both Android and iOS that includes login with Google and Facebook using Firebase Auth.

First I wrote the code in Android Studio in Windows and it works, but when I write it in Android Studio in macOS some lines of code don't work properly. I have configured the iOS project on the Firebase console and on Facebook for developers 'console'. I didn't use CocoaPods to add the frameworks, but I did it manually on Xcode.

Basically, the error is: `The method 'signInWithFacebook' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseAuth'.`

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

signInWithFacebook is no longer exist. 
This is work perfectly!
flutter_facebook_login 3.0.0

```
final FacebookLoginResult facebookLoginResult = await facebookLogin.logIn(['email', 'public_profile']);
FacebookAccessToken facebookAccessToken = facebookLoginResult.accessToken;
AuthCredential authCredential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken: facebookAccessToken.token);
FirebaseUser fbUser;
fbUser = (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(authCredential)).user;
```

Answer (score 16):

Yes, the method `signInWithFacebook` is gone from `FirebaseAuth` now we do this work with `signInWithCredential` method with `AuthCredential` and `FacebookAuthProvider` classes to make autentication process. I will put a snipet with some comments just to illustrate how to do auth in firebase with facebook credentials. I hope it helps...

```dart
/// in some point of your code you will get facebookLoginResult 

final facebookLoginResult = await facebookLogin
  .logInWithReadPermissions(['email', 'public_profile']);
FacebookAccessToken myToken = facebookLoginResult.accessToken;

///assuming sucess in FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn
/// we use FacebookAuthProvider class to get a credential from accessToken
/// this will return an AuthCredential object that we will use to auth in firebase
AuthCredential credential= FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken: myToken.token);

// this line do auth in firebase with your facebook credential.
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = (
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential)
).user;

/// ... do your things
```

Comment: Which package the FacebookAccessToken and facebookLogin login comes from?

Comment: From [flutter_facebook_login](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_facebook_login#-installing-tab-) package.

Comment: @MarcosBoaventura thanks for this tip. I am able get login successfully, but for some reason the user object after this update does not have an email property (displayName is fine).  Any guess why?

Comment: @user1961 I take a look at firebase_auth plugin [CHANGELOG](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth#-changelog-tab-) there is no info about such change  and I've looked also in plugin implementation [here](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/lib/src/user_info.dart) and [here](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/lib/src/firebase_user.dart) all is looking fine.

Comment: @MarcosBoaventura very strange uid/displayName/photoUrl are all returned from the object fine.  Something strange about email as if it does not have authorization.  I'll keep going through the docs.

Comment: @MarcosBoaventura it turned out it was a Firebase issue with their rules about separate users that have the same email.  The second FirebaseUser does not return an email.  I deleted the users and got after that.

Comment: `The method 'logInWithReadPermissions' isn't defined for the class 'FacebookLogin'.`

Comment: fixed error above with `logIn` instead of `logInWithReadPermissions`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `signInWithFacebook` was removed in `0.7.0` and `signInWithCredential` was added instead.

The change log could have been more clear about the change: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth#070

See also: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/commit/a444ad120418d622c4dea2882190968722abbcfe

If you update to a newer plugin version you probably also will https://flutter.io/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility

Comment: I do not know why but now 'signInWithFacebook' and 'signInWithGoogle' work perfectly. I swear I did not touch anything!

Comment: Seems you are using a version before `0.7.0`. Check `pubspec.lock` to see what version of a dependency is actually used in your project.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately [flutter_facebook_login](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_login) 3.0.0 broken in Flutter 1.17.